# Smoothness and algebraicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds

My question is the following : 
given a complex algebraic affine variety $M \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, let us assume that it has moreover a smooth differential structure as a submaifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. I attempt to claim that the algebraic structure is smooth in the very basic sense, that is, if $$M=V(f_1,...f_n)$$ with $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[X_1,...,X_m]$, then there is no point $x \in M$ such that the determinant of the jacobian matrix $(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)_{i,j}$ vanishes.

But i can't prove it, in fact i guess something disgusting could happen...
Any help?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/q/98366/450

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It is an interesting example, but is it smooth as a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$?